# Erro ao tentar abrir arquivo *.FDB no IBExpert

Tags: firebird

Eu preciso abrir um arquivo *.FDB pelo IBExpert, até pouco tempo eu estava conseguindo abri-lo normalmente porém ontem ele começou a dar esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei no painel de controle e o BD Firebird está rodando tudo certo e fiz o teste `Telnet` no prompt de comando, e a porta 3050 que é a do Firebird está conectada também. 

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Meu amigo, verifique no Firewall se a porta citada esta realmente liberada! Você pode ter deixado aberta somente a UDP, você também pode ter instalado algum programa que usa essa porta e nem percebeu!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Como posso verificar se apenas a UDP está liberada? E se por um acaso outro programa estiver utilizando essa porta, como posso liberar ela apenas para o Firebird?

Comment: Acesso o Firewall do Windows pelo menu iniciar, procure por Firewall com opções avançadas! Lá você conseguira encontrar quem esta usando as portas! Caso outro aplicativo esteja usando a porta pelo Firewall você pode mudar a permissão!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Descobri o que era o erro, eu instalei o Delphi 7 no computador, e junto instalou o InterBase, e quando o InterBase foi instalado ele instalou um novo arquivo **gds.dll** que apontava para o Interbase e não para o FireBird.

Comment: Aaa, então existia um detalhe a mais que você não mencionou para nós, bom que resolveu! Nas próximas perguntas não se esqueça de fornecer os detalhes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi necessário desinstalar o InterBase da máquina para que ao reinstalar o FireBird o mesmo pudesse gerar um novo arquivo **gds.dll** que voltasse a apontar para o banco FireBird e não apontasse para o InterBase